# Wordpress the_content hook called twice

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am stuck right now and cant find what I am doing wrong.
I want to append author bio after post content.
Here is what I do.

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'author_bio' );

function author_bio( $content ) {
    if(is_single()){
        $content .= "Author bio..";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

The problem is that the text is outputted twice - before and after the post, I want it to show just once.

Comment: Try `add_filter`


`
function author_bio( $content ) {
    if(is_single()){
        $content .= "Author bio..";
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'author_bio' );`

Comment: there is no difference

Comment: I ended up enqueung a script that hides the first occurence ..I'm still open for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `add_action` to `add_filter`.
2. Remove the filter after it got called.

> It's here because markdown converts the code after the list into normal text!!!

```
add_filter('the_content', 'author_bio');

function author_bio( $content ) {
    if(is_single()){
        $content .= "Author bio..";

        remove_filter('the_content', 'author_bio');
    }

    return $content;
}
```